# Content on HTML/CSS page moves when the 'Tab' key is pressed

Tags: html, css

I've created a custom login page for my Salesforce Community which consists of some HTML and CSS (all within the Visualforce page), but when I use the tab key some content on the page shifts.

From my research it seems to be from the content being larger than the container it is within, but what would be a fix for this? Having some of the content be slightly cut off is part of the style (look and feel) of the page so I'd rather not simply expose the content all the way if possible.

```css
/* **CSS within my Visualforce page** */

/* CSS Reset */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del,
dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub,
sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, button, form, 
fieldset, input, textarea {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  font-size: 100%;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

/* remember to define focus styles! */
 :focus {
  outline: 0;
}

/* remember to highlight inserts somehow! */
ins {
  text-decoration: none;
}

del {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

address, caption, cite, code, dfn, em, strong, var {
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

caption, th {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

html {
  background-color: #3a3a3a;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://subtlepatterns.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/navy_blue.png) repeat;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}

a {
  color: #b1c;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: -180px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

p a {
  color: #a4a4a4;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

p a:hover {
  color: #1d83cc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray
}

<!-- Hyperlink Color -->#warp {
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

form {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

h1 {
  color: #b6b6b6;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 60px;
}

.admin {
  height: 250px;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  border-right: 1px solid #333333;
  text-align: left;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in 100ms;
}

.cms {
  height: 250px;
  top: 70px;
  left: -62px;
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: right;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in 100ms;
}

.admin,
.cms {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.cms h1 {
  margin-left: -10px;
  color: #838385;
}

.roti,
.rota {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.admin:hover h1,
.cms:hover h1 {
  color: #1d83cc;
}

<!-- Header Hover Color -->.rota {
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.roti {
  margin-top: 80px;
  margin-right: 55px;
}

input,
button {
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 8px 6px;
  width: 350px;
  background: white;
  color: black;
  font-size: 10px;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.button {
  margin-left: -230px;
  background: #303030;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

button:hover {
  background: #1d83cc;
  <!-- ???Color -->transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

input:hover {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(29, 131, 204, 1)
}

<!-- Button Hover Color -->input:focus {
  background: gray;
  color: white
}

.up {
  top: 100px;
  left: -60px;
}

.down {
  top: -100px;
  left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<!-- **HTML within my Visualforce page** -->

<div id="warp">
  <form action="" id="formu">
    <div class="admin">
      <div class="rota">
        <h1>PORTAL</h1>
        <apex:inputtext styleClass="input" value="{!username}" html-placeholder="Username" />
        <apex:inputsecret styleClass="input" value="{!password}" html-placeholder="Password" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cms">
      <div class="roti">
        <h1>BW</h1>
        <apex:commandbutton styleClass="button" value="Login" action="{!doLogin}" />
        <p>
          <apex:commandLink value="Forgot password?" action="{!forgotPassword}" />
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the html and css show the problem?

Comment: If 'tab' key is causing layout bug it might be because of focus-state on element accessed by tab-key. pressing tab will cycle through clickable elements on the page & apply the `focus` state. Try removing `:focus {outline: 0;}` or changing it to `:focus {outline: 0;border:2px dashed #f00}` to help show what the problem is. Also `<!-- ... -->` is html-comment, `/* ... */` is css-comment.